# Using SQL Failover Partner with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

Is pyodbc capable of using a failover partner?  ODBC says it's supported so I'm not sure why what I have is not working:

```
db = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', database=DATABASE, server=PRIMARY, failover_partner=SECONDARY)
```

My database is SQL Server 2008.  The only other thing I can do at this point is use a try/except to handle the connection creation but I'd vastly prefer doing this the way I understand SQL is intended to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a conversation with the developer of **pyodbc** module. He says it doesn't have the support for failover partner.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of struggle, found https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-tds/1.8.1.

It supports failover parner server for MS SQL Server :)